# Getting TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object during text input using textiput from react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object

[This error is located at:
in AndroidTextInput (at TextInput.js:1186)
in InternalTextInput (at TextInput.js:1237)
in TextInput (created by TextInputFlat)](https://stackoverflow.com)

am using textinput from react-native-paper

```
 <TextInput
              label="number Key"
              value={number}
              onChangeText={setNumber}
              style={styles.input}
              right={
                number ? (
                  <TextInput.Icon
                    name="close-circle"
                    onPress={() => setNumber('')}
                  />
                ) : null
              }
              keyboardType="default"
            />
```

i want to enter text in reactnative but am getting that cyclicc error